# IPv6 transition, firewall, router or "security switch" with firewall features?

Tags: firewall, switch, ipv6

It seems that I've lost the overview regarding IPv6 and all it's new features...

We own a 3Com / HP OfficeConnect Gigabit VPN Firewall (3CREVF100-73) which has NO IPv6 support.

Because we are migrating our telephone system to SIP / VoIP we will buy soon an used IPv6 "dual-stack" 3Com / HP 4800G PWR (PoE) 48-Port Switch. This so called "layer-4 switch" seems to be much more than just a switch. In fact, it's also a router - with firewall functions like "Denial of Service" preventions etc. The term "switch" seems to be here an absolutely wrong description for this device...

However, my question is now, - do I need in future really a new IPv6 capable firewall? Or is this "secure switch" enough for a small hotel company like we are?

If yes, the 4800G PWR switch will be then directly connected to an IPv6 capable cable-modem, so there will be NO additional devices between. At the end, the "switch" will act as a dual stack DHCP Router with VLAN & firewall functions.

Don't know why, but this topology without an classical firewall makes me a strange feeling...

Comment: Repeat after me: "NAT is not a substitute for a decent firewall."

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams That seems like an oversimplification of the situation, and without reference or context seems out of place.

Answer (score 2):

There's good reason HP was able to buy 3Com for pennies on the dollar, their stuff *ain't good*. The ProCurve and Colubris gear (all under the "ProCurve" name now) is excellent. I would avoid the old 3Com acquisitions if you have any choice in the matter.

As for a firewall, I highly recommend getting a separate device. In your situation an old PC running [pfSense](http://pfsense.org) would be more than enough, support IPv6 and just about anything else you could want (Content Filtering, Captive Portal, and Client Authorization come to mind) with relative ease. If you want a "polished" product, there are a few [companies that sell such appliances](http://pfsense.org/index.php@option=com_content&task=view&id=44&Itemid=50.html). If you want an actual firewall appliance sticking with the major brands is likely your best option (Juniper and Cisco).

Comment: Thanks Chris S for your fast answer. Will check your recommendations. Please note, HP still sells this according to you "bad" 3Com switch under their own brand. So they wouldn't do that if it's really so badly. The 4800G series switches are still also supported. The price for the 48 Port PoE model is new over $5000. We can get it for lesser the half... Anyway, but that was not my question. My original question was, can replace such a "special secure" layer 4 switch a simple entry level firewall? Or can it generally only complement a firewall?

Comment: It can complement a firewall, but it is not good enough (feature and security wise) to replace a real firewall.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your input Sander Steffann. Yes, it seems that most Layer 4 switches can only complement a firewall.

However, I found now the following interesting information at a website called networkworld:
(http://www.networkworld.com/details/725.html)

*Layer 4 switches also offer a powerful combination of Network Address Translation (NAT) with higher-layer address screening. In fact, the term "Layer 4 Switch" is really a misnomer: These products may make forwarding decisions based upon information at any OSI layer from 4 through 7, depending upon the particular product. In fact, some of the so-called "Layer 4 Switches" even monitor the state of individual sessions from beginning to end, just as firewalls do, in which case they're referred to as "session switches."*

So, it looks that there exist some special Layer 4 Switches which are able to substitute a basic firewall. I know, they may be still not as functional as a separate firewall device, but it can do the job of a entry level firewall product. For just a semi-professional use that may be enough.